# Не работает функция ACF delete_row

Tags: wordpress, acf

У ACF есть функция удаления полей: `delete_row($selector, $row, [$post_id])`.
Пишу код для удалаения поля, но он не отрабатывает и возвращает `false`

```
<?php
if ($i == 1) {
     echo "Delete THIS";
     delete_row('certificates', $i, $post->ID);
}
?>
```

Вопрос в том почему это не работает, в Доке ACF написано сделать так, я делаю, но delete_row не отрабатывает и пишет Bool False, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: И где собственно вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том почему это не работает, в Доке ACF написано сделать так, я делаю, но delete_row не отрабатывает и пишет Bool False, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Вопрос должен быть в теле вопроса а не в комментах

Comment: Исправил вопрос